# How to auto-hide ApplicatioWindow menuBar?

Tags: qt, qml

I'd like to have an `ApplicationWindow` have an auto-hiding `menuBar`, which shows up when mouse cursor is positioned on the uppermost part of the window. Is this possible in QML?

PS: I'm using Qt 5.3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can exploit internal properties, i.e. properties starting with "__". Since they are internal, functionality could break in future releases even if IMO it is unlikely in this case.

By using internal properties you can exploit `__contentItem`, the graphical container of the `MenuBar` and animate its properties to achieve the desired result. Here is a possible approach; it works with Qt 5.3/ Qt 5.4/ Qt 5.5 (the ones I could test it on):

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: app
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 300

    property real hideValue: 0
    Behavior on hideValue {
        NumberAnimation {duration: 200}
    }

    menuBar:  MenuBar {
        id: menu
        //__contentItem.scale: value                        // (1)
        //__contentItem.opacity: hideValue                  // (2)
        __contentItem.transform: Scale {yScale: hideValue}  // (3)

        Menu {
            id: m1
            title: "File"
            MenuItem { text: "Open..."
                onTriggered: {
                   hideValue = 0                            // hide the bar
                }
            }
            MenuItem { text: "Close"
                onTriggered: {
                   hideValue = 0                            // hide the bar
                }
            }
        }
    }


    Button{
        id: b1
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "CLICK ME!"
        width: 100
        height: 100
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: ma1
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        height: menu.__contentItem.implicitHeight
        hoverEnabled: true

        onEntered: {
            hideValue = 1                            // show the bar
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: ma2
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        z: -1

        onEntered: {
            m1.__dismissMenu()
            hideValue = 0                            // hide the bar
        }
    }
}
```

Summarizing the code:

- Two `MouseArea` are defined: `ma1` which covers the `MenuBar` and `ma2` which fills the `ApplicationWindow`. The latter has a `z` negative to be positioned *under* any other element of the window, inclusing `ma1`: this way it cannot interfere with events related to any element added (such as the example button `b1`).
- `ma1` sets a property called `hideValue` to `1` whereas `ma2` brings it back to `0`. The property is used over a visual property of `__contentItem` (see `(1)`, `(2)` and `(3)` in the code) to hide/show the `MenuBar`. A simple `Behaviour` over the `hideValue` property ensures that the transition is smooth.
- Internal function `__dismissMenu()` is used to ensure that an opened `Menu` is closed when the `MenuBar` loses focus.
- When a `MenuItem` is triggered the `hideValue` property is directly reset to ensure correct hiding.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get some results with this code:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: app

    MenuBar {
        id: menu
        Menu {
            title: "Menu 1"
            MenuItem {
                text: "item 1"
            }
            MenuItem {
                action: "item 2"
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        height: 20
        hoverEnabled: true

        onEntered: {
            if (app.menuBar === menu)
                app.menuBar = null;
            else
                app.menuBar = menu;
        }
    }
}
```

The change however is abruptly and QML debugging report errors when trying to access `null.__contentItem` when the bar is hidden. And, of course, there's an absolute size in the code which could cause problems.