# QML - Show MenuBar or Menu items by click event

Tags: android, qt, drop-down-menu, qml, qtquick2

Is there a way to show `MenuBar` and `MenuItem` by `onClicked` event of any control (or any other event)? I've tried to use `popup` function of Menu but it did nothing. The purpose is to Re-implement menu button in `ApplicationWindow` on Android application build to make look alike different than current menu button, or use it by clicking on any other widget to popup any other menu. I learning QML about 3 weeks, can someone help me with it? I think it should be quite easy, and I want to make it more simpler and logical. Appreciated for any code examples.

Comment: Does [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27326837/2538363) work for your use case? You can easily change the event which triggers the `MenuBar`.

Comment: Hi, will check it now

Comment: Yes, it's true, but I was misunderstood my primary purpose, actually I need another thing and just posted answer to my own question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I was wrong about direction of my question. Just understood that I need to show `Menu` and it's really quite easy done with `popup` function. For example standard template of QtQuick project with Button to show specified menu.

```
Menu {
    id: menuFile
    title: qsTr("&File")
    MenuItem {
        text: qsTr("&Open")
        onTriggered: messageDialog.show(qsTr("Open action triggered"));
    }
    MenuItem {
        text: qsTr("E&xit")
        onTriggered: Qt.quit();
    }
}

Button{
    onClicked: menuFile.popup()
}
```

But I've tried to show `MenuBar` with all the menus listed and it's really need another way of functionality.

Comment: Ok, reading your question I was fooled by the text. I'm glad that you solved your issue. :)